# Use angular translate static-loader-file for date picker (with several locale files)

Tags: json, angularjs, datepicker, locale, angular-translate

I need to translate the angular date picker. I've installed angular-translate-loader-static-files, downloaded locale files and included the index.html.

```
<script src="external/angular-translate-loader-static-files-master/angular-translate-loader-static-files.min.js"></script>
```

also added this part in app.js

```
 $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({ 
    prefix: 'locale/angular-locale_',
    suffix: '.js'
});
```

But as a fact - js file that is the last declared in index.html (  ) is used when switch between languages.
So, if change the order 
`<script src="external/locale/angular-locale_en.json"></script> 
 <script src="external/locale/angular-locale_es.json"></script>`, then 'es' will be used for date picker.

Locales are able to be downloaded here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ngLocale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set you preferred language, so something like

```
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
```

Not sure what you want your preferred language to be but setting a default will help.